# Asynchronous call in componentWillMount finishes after render method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I am trying to perform an asynchronous call to an API in the componentWillMount method. Indeed I would like the `render` method to executed after the componentWillMount method as I need to pass `props` to the component in my `render` method.

Here is my code :

```
class TennisSearchResultsContainer extends React.Component {
  componentWillMount () {
    // TODO: Build markers for the map
    // TODO: Check courtsResults object and database for tennis court
    this.courtsMarkers = this.props.courtsResults.map((court) => {
      return new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(JSON.parse(court.LOC).coordinates[1], JSON.parse(court.LOC).coordinates[0]),
        title: court.NAME,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
      });
    });
  }
  render () {
    return <TennisSearchResults criterias={this.props.criterias} courtsMarkers={this.courtsMarkers} />;
  }
}
```

I don't understand then why my render method seems to do not wait for the asynchronous call to finish and pass undefined props to my child component...

Am I right? And what should I do to fix that? What is the way to handle this?

Comment: you need to use `componentDidMount` instead as `componentWillMount` only runs once before the component is mounted to the DOM. So, there's not guarantee that component will be rendered after the AJAX call.

Comment: Which part of your code is async? There are a lot of Google Maps calls and it isn't clear if it is one of them, or something else.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

You might need to understand javascript async behavior better. Async means "don't wait". That the task will happen in the background and other code will continue to execute. A good way to manage this is to set state on your component. For example, when you enter `componentDidMount` set a `loading` state to `true`. Then when your async function completes, set that state to `false`. In your `render` function you can then either display a "loading..." message or the data.

Here is some code that shows a simplified example of fetching data async and how you could handle that in React. Open the developer tools in your browser and look at the console output to understand the React lifecycle better.

EDIT: Code has been updated to use the new React Lifecycle recommendations as of April 2018. In summary, I replaced `componentWillMount` with the safer `componentDidMount`.

It might seem inefficient to update the state *after* the component has already mounted, as 'component**DID**mount' correctly implies. However, per the [official React documentation on componentDidMount](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount):

"If you need to load data from a remote endpoint, this is a good place to instantiate the network request."

"Calling `setState()` in this method will trigger an extra rendering, but it will happen before the browser updates the screen. This guarantees that even though the `render()` will be called twice in this case, the user won’t see the intermediate state."

Here's the complete example code:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();

    console.log('This happens 1st.');

    this.state = {
      loading: 'initial',
      data: ''
    };

  }

  loadData() {
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
      setTimeout(() => {
        console.log('This happens 6th (after 3 seconds).');
        resolve('This is my data.');
      }, 3000);
    });

    console.log('This happens 4th.');

    return promise;
  }

  componentDidMount() {

    console.log('This happens 3rd.');

    this.setState({ loading: 'true' });
    this.loadData()
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('This happens 7th.');
      this.setState({
        data: data,
        loading: 'false'
      });
    });
  }  

  render() {

    if (this.state.loading === 'initial') {
      console.log('This happens 2nd - after the class is constructed. You will not see this element because React is still computing changes to the DOM.');
      return <h2>Intializing...</h2>;
    }


    if (this.state.loading === 'true') {
      console.log('This happens 5th - when waiting for data.');
      return <h2>Loading...</h2>;
    }

    console.log('This happens 8th - after I get data.');
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Got some data!</p>
        <p>{this.state.data}</p>
       </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <MyComponent />,
  document.getElementsByClassName('root')[0]
);
```

And here is the [working example on CodePen](http://codepen.io/tchaffee/pen/jBgMQy).

Finally, I think this image of the modern React lifecycle [created by React maintainer Dan Abramov](https://twitter.com/dan_abramov/status/981712092611989509) is helpful in visualizing what happens and when.

[image]

NOTE that as of of React 16.4, this lifecycle diagram has a small inaccuracy: `getDerivedStateFromProps` is now also called after `setState` as well as `forceUpdate`. See this article from the official React blog about the [Bugfix for getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/05/23/react-v-16-4.html#bugfix-for-getderivedstatefromprops)

This [interactive version of the React lifecycle diagram](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/) created by Wojciech Maj allows you to select React version >16.04 with the latest behavior (still accurate as of React 16.8.6, March 27, 2019). Make sure you check the "Show less common lifecycles" option.

Comment: Note that as of React 16.4, this lifecycle diagram has a small inaccuracy: `getDerivedStateFromProps` is now also called after a `setState` (as well as a `forceUpdate`?). See https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/05/23/react-v-16-4.html#bugfix-for-getderivedstatefromprops

Comment: @MattKramer thank you for pointing that out. I have updated the answer to include that note.

Answer (score -3):

The above answer is probably overkill for what you are trying to do. All you need to do is make compoentDidMount an async function. Then you can use the await keyword on a function call that returns a promise.

```html
class MyComponent extends React.Component {

  async componentWillMount () {
  
    await myAsyncCall();
    
  }
  
  render () {
    
  }

}
```

Comment: `await` keyword is NOT a means of converting asynchronous functions into synchronous functions. You need multithreading and concurrency mechanisms for that. Your code would work the same if you removed `async` and `await` keywords. Your code is equivalent to:

`class MyComponent extends React.Component {
componentWillMount () {
myAsyncCall().then(() => {}); /*do nothing*/
}
render () {
}
}`