# Updating state before render: propType marked as required but undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having an issue with a component that has some required propTypes.

The error I'm getting is:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `firstname` is marked as required in `UserHeader`, but its value is `undefined`.
in UserHeader (at App.js:32)
in App (created by Connect(App))
in Connect(App) (at index.js:17)
in Provider (at index.js:16)
```

And my code ...

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import ErrorBoundary from './containers/ErrorBoundary'
import UserHeader from './components/UserHeader';
import Header from './components/Header';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    // Pretend this is an API call that takes a second
    setTimeout(() => {
      const data = {
        user: {
          firstname: 'bughunter',
          level: 55
        }
      };
      this.props.didMountHandler(data)
    }, 1000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ErrorBoundary>
        <Header />
        <UserHeader 
          firstname={this.props.firstname}
          level={this.props.level}
        />
      </ErrorBoundary>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    firstname: state.user.firstname,
    level: state.user.level
  }
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  didMountHandler: data => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'USER_DATA_RECEIVED',
      data
    });
  }
})

const AppContainer = connect(  
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(App);

export default AppContainer;
```

I'm modifying the state before the `render` method has called so I'm confused how props for `UserHeader` are being checked before the `setTimeout` has finished?

How am I able to hold off on rendering/propChecking until `setTimeout` has completed?

I thought about setting some initial default state when creating the store, like so:

```
{
    user: {
        firstname: '',
        level: 0
    }
}
```

... but that seems a little hackish.

Comment: May be you would want to checkout this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312223/asynchronous-call-in-componentwillmount-finishes-after-render-method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are NOT modifying the state before `render`, because you are using a setTimeout. Render does not wait for your `setTimeout` and is directly called after `componentWillMount` is called.

You have to set some default values in the redux reducer. You can just set in the reducer

```
user: null,
....
```

and when rendering check if you have the user or not

```
render() {
    const { user } = this.props;
    { user && <UserHeader firstname={user.firstname} level={user.level} /> }
```

And in `mapStateToProps` just copy the entire `user` obj:

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    user: state.user
  }
};
```

---

There are also other ways to do it. You could just set default values for `firstName` and `level` in the reducer as you suggested, or you could always render the `UserHeader` with a `user` prop and decide in it what to display if you don't have the values subValues set.

Answer (score 0):

Add a loader component or null like below. And the use local state.

```
state = { initialized: false }

componentWillMount() {
// Pretend this is an API call that takes a second
setTimeout(() => {
  const data = {
    user: {
      firstname: 'bughunter',
      level: 55
    }
  };
  this.props.didMountHandler(data)
  this.setState({ initialized: true });
}, 1000);
}

render(){
   if(!this.state.initialized){
       return null;
   }

   return (
     <ErrorBoundary>
        <Header />
        <UserHeader 
           firstname={this.props.firstname}
           level={this.props.level}
        />
     </ErrorBoundary>
   );
}
```