# render() is called before componentWillMount() is completed

Tags: firebase, react-native

I am a bit confused...the render() is invoked before the componentWillMount()

```
 import React,{Component} from 'react';
import {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
AsyncStorage
} from 'react-native';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import Chart from 'react-native-chartjs';
import moment from 'moment'
import { Icon } from 'react-native-elements'
import PureChart from 'react-native-pure-chart';



export default class History extends Component {
  state={LoginId: ''}
constructor(){
     super();
     console.log("in constructor");
     global.arrayDate = [];
     global.arrayStep = [];
     //sampleData = [];
     global.sampleData= [];

 }
 componentWillMount() {
/*console.log(" in ComponentWillMount")
const LoginId = AsyncStorage.getItem("LoginId")
this.setState({ LoginId: JSON.parse(LoginId) });
AsyncStorage.getItem("LoginId").then((value) => {
  this.setState({"LoginId": value});
console.log("in CMW", LoginId)
})*/
console.log(" in CWM")
AsyncStorage.getItem("LoginId").then((value) => {
  this.setState({"LoginId": value});
console.log("Loginid in componentwillmount is", this.state.LoginId)
})
.then( res => {


console.log("configuring firebase");
var range = moment().week();
var date;
var ra= range.toString()

var docRef= firebase.firestore().collection('data').doc(this.state.LoginId).collection('y').doc('eks').collection(ra);
docRef.orderBy("weekDayNo").get().then(snapshot => {
          snapshot.forEach(doc => {
date=doc.data().weekDayName
arrayDate.push(date);
step=doc.data().Count
arrayStep.push(step);

})
})
console.log(arrayStep);


a0 = arrayDate[0]
console.log('a0 ',a0)

a1 = arrayDate[1]
console.log('a1 ',a1)

a2 = arrayDate[2]
console.log('a2 ',a2)


a3 = arrayDate[3]
console.log('a3 ',a3)


a4 = arrayDate[4]
console.log('a4 ',a4)


a5 = arrayDate[5]
console.log('a5 ',a5)


a6 = arrayDate[6]
console.log('a6 ',a6)

b0 = arrayStep[0]
console.log('b0 ',arrayStep[0])

b1 = arrayStep[1]
console.log('b1 ',arrayStep[1])

b2 = arrayStep[2]
console.log('b2 ',arrayStep[2])

b3 = arrayStep[3]
console.log('b3 ',arrayStep[3])

b4 = arrayStep[4]
console.log('b4 ',arrayStep[4])

b5 = arrayStep[5]
console.log('b5 ',arrayStep[5])

b6 = arrayStep[6]
console.log('b6 ',arrayStep[6])


console.log("display chart")


})

}
 render() {

     console.log("in render")
   sampleData = [
        {x: '2018-01-01', y: 30},
        {x: '2018-01-02', y: 200},
        {x: '2018-01-03', y: 170},
        {x: '2018-01-04', y: 250},
        {x: '2018-01-05', y: 10},
   {x: '2018-01-04', y: 250},
        {x: '2018-01-05', y: 10}
   ]
 



    //this.getChartData();


  return(

<View>
 <PureChart data={sampleData} type='bar' backgroundColor="#8c8c8c" highlightColor="#ef4048" height={350}  defaultColumnWidth={40} />
</View>
)
}


}
```

here in componentWillMount(), I am retrieving the userid from the async storage through that id I am fetching details from the firestore. The retrieved data should be displayed in the graph i.e. react-native-pure-chart. For now, I'm giving the static data in the 'sampleData array' but before the componentWillMount() is completed the render() is being invoked and this can be seen in the console logs as displayed below:

> in constructor
>
> [18:35:13]  in ComponenrWillMount
>
> [18:35:13] in render
>
> [18:35:13] in render
>
> [18:35:13] Loginid in componentwillmount is "nabc"
>
> [18:35:13] configuring firebase........etc

since the componentWillMount() contains many lines it only executes the first line and jumped to render and again coming back to componentWillMount(),

I need to complete the whole componentWillMount() then the render() should be invoked so that the graph will receive the data which it wants...

can anyone help me in this how to complete the whole componentWillMount() then the render() should invoked?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think Perhaps because of setState in componentWillMount? Or componentWillMount behaviour is unstable

Comment: thnq@Think-Twice...
But I didn't understand about the componentWillMount behavior unstable..what does it mean?

Comment: Take a look at this SO question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312223/asynchronous-call-in-componentwillmount-finishes-after-render-method

Answer (score 0):

I've been learning about this recently - you should carry out your Async calls in `componentDidMount` really.

`...WillMount` will not return any Async calls before the first `render()`.

In ES6 the `constructor()` is the same as the `componentWillMount()`...so you don't really need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

you are doing async operation in componentWillMount, asynchronous operation means that a process operates independently of other processes, so it will not stop your code.

your code will run in this way

1. invoke constructor
2. execute all code inside contructor
3. then invoke componentWillMount
4. initiate async operation in cwm ---> they will run independently
5. async 1
6. async 2
7. invoke render()
8. executing lines inside render one by one...
9. aysnc 1 completes // will console whatever you have written
10. continue executing lines inside render one by one...
11. aysnc 2 completes // will console whatever you have written

I hope you will understand feel free to ask questions.

Comment: yeah @Rajat..I understood