# TypeError: null is not an object while mapping over an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native

Working on [Let’s Build: Cryptocurrency Native Mobile App With React Native + Redux — Chapter IV](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-how-to-build-a-rn-redux-cryptocurrency-app-chapter-iv-b0e0c5ca2dca)

I'm using the [CoinMarketCap API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api) to return info about different currencies to an array. When I call `renderCoinCards()` from the `render()` method of my component, I get `TypeError: null is not an object while mapping over an array (evaluating 'crypto.data.map')`.

### `renderCoinCards`

```
renderCoinCards() {
    const { crypto } = this.props;
    return crypto.data.map((coin) => 
        <CoinCard 
            key={coin.name}
            coin_name={coin.name}
            symbol={coin.symbol}
            price_usd={coin.price_usd}
            percent_change_24h={coin.percent_change_24h}
            percent_change_7d={coin.percent_change_7d}
        />
    ) 
}
```

Here's what I received from the API call. I logged the `crypto` and, as expected, I see an array of objects. Why can't I `map` over it?

### `console.log(crypto)`

```
  "crypto": Object {
    "data": Array [
      Object {
        "24h_volume_usd": "8453833004.26",
        "available_supply": "17433412.0",
        "id": "bitcoin",
        "last_updated": "1545338123",
        "market_cap_usd": "70044797328.0",
        "max_supply": "21000000.0",
        "name": "Bitcoin",
        "percent_change_1h": "-2.22",
        "percent_change_24h": "5.95",
        "percent_change_7d": "19.47",
        "price_btc": "1.0",
        "price_usd": "4017.84787328",
        "rank": "1",
        "symbol": "BTC",
        "total_supply": "17433412.0",
      },
      Object {
        "24h_volume_usd": "1030004521.77",
        "available_supply": "40762365544.0",
        "id": "ripple",
        "last_updated": "1545338105",
        "market_cap_usd": "15003231633.0",
        "max_supply": "100000000000",
        "name": "XRP",
        "percent_change_1h": "-2.05",
        "percent_change_24h": "1.31",
        "percent_change_7d": "22.02",
        "price_btc": "0.00009160",
        "price_usd": "0.3680657742",
        "rank": "2",
        "symbol": "XRP",
        "total_supply": "99991744391.0",
      },
      Object {...},
      Object {...},
      Object {...}
      ... 
      }
```

### `componentDidMount`

Swapped `componentWillMount` (deprecated), in favor of [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount), as suggested in the React Docs.

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.FetchCoinData();
  }
```

Comment: Isn't the crypto prop being populated from an async/promise based function? Maybe it isn't available (e.g, is equal null) at that time?

Comment: Thanks @ggderas! I am fetching the data in `componentWillMount`. Shouldn't it be done loading by then?

Comment: Checking this out now https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43312223/asynchronous-call-in-componentwillmount-finishes-after-render-method

Comment: good thread, you should probably try to clone the specific object at different times, before rendering, after renred, etc. Don't just console.log it, but make a clone with lodash or something.

Comment: Ahh ok thanks! I'll keep working with what you told me. This was helpful!

Comment: Oh yeah, I logged it in the line right before `crypto.data.map`, so it's loaded at that point.

Comment: Do you mind sharing the componentWillMount piece of code?